# Calling processing constexpr at runtime. C++

Tags: c++, c++11, try-catch, c++14, constexpr

Please see the code below:

```
#include <iostream>

constexpr int f(int a, int b)
{
    return a<b? a : throw std::out_of_range("out of range");    
}

int main() 
{
    try
    {
        int n = 0;
        f(5, n);
    }
    catch(const std::exception& ex)
    {
        std::cout<<"Exception caught"<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<ex.what()<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

I know that constexprt functions are processed at compile time. So how it came that I can pass a "runtime" local varialbe to it and use it in try-catch block again in runtime? Maybe I am missing smth regargind constexprt functions?

Comment: When constexpr function is called with one or more values that are not known during compilation, it acts like normal function. Which means it computes result at runtime. You don’t need two functions to perform the same operation,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I know that constexprt functions are processed at compile time.

Inaccurate. A `constexpr` function *may* be used where a constant expression is *required*, if the stars align. That means it must satisfy certain requirements, but it's still a function. And you can still use it as one.

In your case the function is compiled and called at run-time.

If you were to use it where a constant expression is required, and there the branch with the `throw` was used, then you'd be seeing a stream of problem coming your way.